# How to programmatically list wiki pages with Azure Dev Ops Service rest API

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to use the Azure Dev Ops rest API to retrieve all the wiki pages from a wiki on my azure dev ops site.  Though I am able to retrieve the main wiki with: 
https://dev.azure.com/{project name}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wiki identifier}/

if I add /pages like so:
https://dev.azure.com/{project name}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wiki identifier}/pages

like it says on the documentation, I get a 404 page not found error.  Are there more reqired fields here that I am missing?  The only header I am currently passing is my PAT.

Comment: Hi, how is this going? Can you programmatically list the wiki pages with rest API successfully now? Feel free to share your progress with us:)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this api:

```
Get  https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wikiIdentifier}/pages?path=/&recursionLevel=OneLevel&api-version=5.1
```

**Note**: If you want to list all of wiki pages, need to specified the value of `recursionLevel` in the url. This is the key word which specify the **Recursion level for subpages retrieval.**

For more details about this recursionLevel:

[image]

You can also refer to this doc: [Get page as JSON with recursion level](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages/get%20page?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#get-page-as-json-with-recursion-level) for more sample.

In addition, for **programatically** list wiki pages with rest API, here has an **sample** which execute with powershell can for you refer:

```
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wikiIdentifier}/pages?path=/&recursionLevel=OneLevel&api-version=5.1"
$connectionToken="{Your PAT token}"
$base64AuthInfo = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$projects = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method GET
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($projects| ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```